# merge the 2 different codes to get 1 code

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, html, multi-vendor

we are working on marketplace [multi vendor] site.
we are using 2 different types of codes to load the quantity in different places in the site.

**code 1** :

```
<span id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?></span>
  <input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "qty" value = "<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" />
```

**code 2** :

```
<?php
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_products/product_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_products/product_qty')){?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_products/product_qty') ?>"/>
    <?php
    } ?>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="stock" class="required-entry validate-number input-text" name="stock" id="stock" value="<?php echo number_format($qtyStock, 2, '.', '')?>"/>
</div>
```

I want to keep the type , id , name of code 1 and i want to use the "code 2 " part to get the quantity. I want  to merge the code1 and code 2.

In code 1 , i want to keep html, css , javascript part. 
in code 2, i want to keep php part.

I need the code after merging code 1 and code 2

please let me know if you need any clarifications

Comment: did both are same js script?

Comment: no diffeent js.....

Comment: use this  value="<?php echo number_format($qtyStock, 2, '.', '')?> in code1 before that you have to call all object on that .pthml file

Comment: @Kothari before quantity was displaying like this : "10"

i added your code below code 1.

after that quantity is displaying like this : "10 0.00"

can you inform how to call all object on that .phtml file

code 1 complete code : http://pastebin.com/nCkTJHb4

code 2 complete code : http://pastebin.com/GYnYvWhT

Comment: what is the $qtyStock? what value stored under $qtyStock?

Comment: why you are using number format in that and where you get the value of $qtyStock.

Comment: @Kothari qtyStock is default extension code , can you check this site : http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

Comment: @QaisarSatti that code was provided by extension team.....

Comment: ok what value stored under $qtyStock

Comment: $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($urlid)->getQty();

Comment: ok you just call all object in your code 1 .phtml

Comment: this is code2.phtml : http://pastebin.com/GYnYvWhT, here what code i have to copy and paste in  code 1.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<?php
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_products/product_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_products/product_qty')){?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_products/product_qty') ?>"/>
    <?php
    } ?>


 <?php $qtyStock=(int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>

    <span id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?></span>
      <input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "qty" value = "<?php echo $qtyStock ?>" />
```

Comment: same result , its not working....

Comment: updated try it now..

Comment: unfotunately, this also not working.....

Comment: what is the out at-least tell me and what is not working on that?

Comment: extension team provide an option to update the quantity . there its working fine. [code 2 ]

i implemented another code to update the quantity . there we have problem. [ code 1 ]

we provide an option to seller to add the product in 2 ways.

one is normal adding product.[seller 1 ] one is assigning the same product. [seller 2 ]

in backend quantity is displaying by adding both normal quantity and assigned quantity.

this is the problem. if  i use the same code what extension team used to update the quantity

than everyhting will be fine.

Comment: name="stock" id="stock" change these too then extension js will work

Comment: <span id="stock"><?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?></span>
      <input type = "text" id = "stock" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "stock" value = "<?php echo $qtyStock ?>" />      i tried this code , but quantity is not updating now....

Comment: is there is js of extension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31496/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-2-and-qaisar-satti).